# How to install rt73usb in Ubuntu Server 12.04.4?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, server, ssh

How can I install rt73 on Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 LTS?

I have installed Ubuntu Server on an old Laptop (Advent 7109B) and wireless is not working by default due to missing drivers.

I found online I needed rt73.

`lsmod | grep rt` gives me this:

```
rt73usb                31360  0 
rt2x00usb              20161  1 rt73usb
rt2x00lib              53673  2 rt73usb,rt2x00usb
mac80211              534884  2 rt2x00usb,rt2x00lib
cfg80211              416271  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
parport                40930  1 lp
crc_itu_t              12627  2 rt73usb,firewire_core
```

I have SSH access to it by having the laptop plugging in via ehternet.

Any ideas how I can get Wifi working?

EDIT: Here are results from terdon's comment:

`iwconfig`:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`/sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan`:

```
wlan0     Failed to read scan data : Network is down
```

`lspci | grep Net` returns nothing.

Comment: What makes you think you need rt73usb? What is your wireless card? Have you actually attempted to connect to any networks? Can you see any networks listed in the networkmanager applet? Please [edit] your question and add the output of these commands: `iwconfig`, `/sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan` (change `wlan0` to the name of your wireless device returned by `iwconfig`) and `lspci | grep Net`.

Comment: Added. I read online that Advent 7109B laptops require rt73.

Comment: Try `lspci | grep -i net` and if that returns nothing as well, just post the output of `lspci` alone.

Comment: `lscpi | grep -i net` returned `06:05.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)`

Comment: What does this tell us? sudo ifconfig wlan0 up and next: sudo iwlist wlan0 scan

Comment: @chili555 I just wanted to make sure the OP had correctly identified the wireless NIC. I'm still not sure, it would be found when grepping `lspci` for net, James, can you see an entry for your wireless card in the output of `lspci`? And definitely try chili555's suggestion.

Comment: @terdon The usual method is lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: @chili555 sweet! Thanks, I didn't know that one.

Comment: There is no wifi definition in `lspci` and `lspci -nn | grep 0280` returns nothing. Just going to try chilli555's method now

Comment: LOLOL! We needn't check lspci since it's a USB device: lsusb

Comment: `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` returned nothing (which i think its supposed to) and `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` has come up with wireless networks near the device. Does this mean wifi is working and that I just need to set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a server, without a desktop environment and therefor without Network Manager, wireless is not going to connect to any old possibly insecure network. You must specify the network you want and supply a password. I suggest you amend your /etc/network/interfaces file so as to add the wireless details at the end:

```
#auto eth0
iface eth0 dhcp <--or however it reads now
#Do NOT comment out eth0 until wireless is working reliably and double-checked

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
wpa-ssid <your_network>
wpa-psk <your_password>
```

I suggest a static IP for a server so you can easily ssh and ftp into it. Of course, select an address outside the range used by the DHCP server in the router, switch, or access point. Substitute your details here.

Get the system to re-read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0
```

Check to see if you connected:

```
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

Comment: `sudo ifdown wlan0` says `ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured` and when I do `sudo ifup -v wlan0` the last line says `Failed to bring up wlan0.`

Comment: Does ifconfig say wlan0 is present? UP BROADCAST RUNNING? I assume you used appropriate network numbers. It may take a reboot. Then see if you can ping -c3 192.168.1.150 or whatever you set for the address.

Comment: ifconfig does have wlan0 present and UP BROADCAST says RUNNING. I don't get a response on ping for its new IP and booting now takes much longer because it sits on `waiting for network configuration...`

Comment: I assume this is after a reboot. What do the logs tell us? dmesg | grep -e wlan -e rt7 Paste the result here and give us a link in the reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I did a reboot (to plug back in the ethernet so I can ssh back into it) and did the command. This was my result: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7086791/

Comment: Your paste looks like the wireless connected quite perfectly. Is the system waiting for ethernet connection because it is declared in /etc/network/interfaces? Once you get wireless working, you can comment out ethernet like in my edit above, but not until.

Comment: I'm going to try commenting the ethernet out, unplugging ethernet and rebooting. I have direct access with the machine anyway as its next to my router.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13589/discussion-between-chili555-and-jamesking56)

Comment: chat doesn't seem to be working, it says I'm not logged in even though I'm logged in on AskUbuntu... which is strange

Comment: scratch that, I'm in.